# Form not uploading file in codeigniter 2.0

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have tried every possible method but no success. Just trying to upload file using code igniter but not working the error I am getting

```
<pre>Array
(
 [error] => <p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>
)
```

I have tried in normal core php at my local host that works fine but not working with code igniter. It is simply not picking the file. If I check with `var_dump($_FILES['fileToUpload']);` the result will be `array(0)`.

**Form Code**

```
<form id="contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Main/do_upload">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
</form>
```

**Controller Code**

```
$config = array(
    'upload_path' => "./uploads/",
    'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
    'overwrite' => TRUE,
    'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
    'max_height' => "768",
    'max_width' => "1024"
);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if($this->upload->do_upload())
{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($data);
    // $this->load->view('upload_success',$data);
}else{
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($error);
}
```

**config**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array("session", "email", "database");
$autoload['helper'] = array("url", "file", "form");
```

Is there anything I am not aware of ? Please guide I am stuck here.

Comment: can you try site_url() instead of base_url and use name userfile instead of fileToUpload? and do echo var_dump($_FILES);die; before the $config array and paste that outpur here

Answer (score 1):

You missed input file name in `do_upload()`:

Use :

```
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image_file'))
{
   //$this->upload->display_errors()
}
else
{
   //$this->upload->data()
}
```

Instead of:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload())
```

Comment: I try that before. As I said in my question  "  If I check with var_dump($_FILES['fileToUpload']); the result will be array(0). "

Comment: If I do it in codeigniter way I got this error   <pre>Array
(
 [error] => <p>You did not select a file to upload.</p>
)    I am doing this with if($this->upload->do_upload("fileToUpload"))

Comment: echo $_FILES['fileToUpload'][tmp_name]; & check the file name

Answer (score 0):

You miss parameters in `$this->upload->do_upload` Pleas check below code.

```
public function do_upload(){
        $config = array(
            'upload_path' => "assets/uploads/",
            'allowed_types' => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf",
            'overwrite' => TRUE,
            'max_size' => "2048000", // Can be set to particular file size , here it is 2 MB(2048 Kb)
            'max_height' => "768",
            'max_width' => "1024"
        );
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('fileToUpload'))
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($data);
            // $this->load->view('upload_success',$data);
        }else{
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors()); 
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($error);
        }
    }
```

Pass your file upload name in `$this->upload->do_upload('fileToUpload')`